# INSERT Row If Does Not Exist mysql with POST

Tags: php, android, exists

I have read all the information in the previous questions and I did, but unfortunately I did not receive a positive answer.
I want to store the information that is posted from Android into Database
Provided that this information is not already available
This is my php code and it's not a problem to send information from Android :

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', '***');

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $photo = $_POST['photo'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $strSQL = " INSERT INTO checkout_page (code , username ,photo , isactive) VALUES('$code' , '$username' , '$photo' , 'TRUE')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL)){
        echo "insert";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "problem";
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit more? What does your current code do? Does it insert duplicate records? Does it not work? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Oper, could you please explicit the problem you encountered? If You want the row to be unique in DB then ensure one of the entered keys is UNIQUE.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The code is completely correct and works, but I want this code to run only when it has not already been executed. Clearer when the row is not already added

Comment: Also, some advice -- don't use strings like `TRUE` and `FALSE` for boolean fields. Instead use values that evaluate correctly in a boolean context, like 0 and 1.

Comment: _"when the row is not already added"_ Do you mean the whole row, with those same values? Or just any row for that code?

Comment: @AlexHowansky no , i mean any row for any data posted from android

Comment: _"any row for any data"_ Please post examples of data which should be allowed and which shouldn't be.

Comment: @AlexHowansky With the code I've written, the information I get from Android comes in the row in the database. I want this information to be placed once and not inserted for the second time or updated with new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** .
this is solution :

```
$strSQL = " INSERT INTO page (id , code , username ) VALUES('$id' , '$code' , '$username' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code='$code')";
```

tnx everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to make sure you have a primary key or unique key in your checkout_page table, and instead of doing an if else, you would do try/catch. Your code will execute everytime, but will only insert one record for each code for example (assuming code is the PK).
Another way to do so is to run a query before your insert to check if you already have this record inserted, and only execute your insert when the query returns no results.

Comment: Never rely on the result of a select to determine if you can subsequently insert.